# How do you pass data from current activity to Previous activity

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to pass a value from Activity 3 to Activity 2 but I am getting null Value. If I click Back button its going to previous Activity but value is null.  Added the suggested Approach code below. but still not able to get the results.

```
Suggested Approach:

Activity :3

   override fun onBackPressed() {
        sendDataBackToPreviousActivity()
        super.onBackPressed()
     }

    private fun sendDataBackToPreviousActivity()
    {
        val navBarTitle21=intent.getStringExtra(TestProjectMenuViewHolder.TEST_TITLE_NAME)
        val intent=Intent().apply { putExtra("ReturnMessage",navBarTitle21)}
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)
    }


    Activity:2

    Main Class:
        companion object {
        const val START_ACTIVITY_3_REQUEST_CODE = 0
    }
  val intent=Intent(this,TestProjectMenuDetail::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, START_ACTIVITY_3_REQUEST_CODE)

    Declared outside Main Class:

       override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == START_ACTIVITY_3_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val message = data!!.getStringExtra("ReturnMessage")
                Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                println("Message Value: $message")
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

First Approach:
    Activity:3
    val navBarTitle= intent.getStringExtra(TestMenuViewHolder.TEST_TITLE_KEY)
        supportActionBar?.title=navBarTitle//Something Like "StackOverFlow". THis is for back Button
            TestMenuDetail:
            val navBarTitle2=intent.getStringExtra(TestMenuViewHolder.TEST_TITLE_NAME)
            val TestVar=Intent(this@TestMenuDetail,TestMenuList::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("TestVar2",navBarTitle2)
            println("Test Value $navBarTitle2")//Test Value Hello

    Activity:2      
    TestMenuList:
            val navBarTitle3=intent.getStringExtra("TestVar2")
            println("Helllo Test: $navBarTitle3")//Helllo Test: null
```

Comment: You should use [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: @Onik Thanks for your response. Why I am getting null value in my Activity2? Why I need to use startActivityForResult() instead of intent. I have never used this option before.

Comment: Please show the part, where you actually start activity 2. You omitted so much of your implementation that it is hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I am using ViewHolder in Activity 1 and Activity 2. If I click the item then using setOnClickListener value is passed from Activity1---2---3. This is from Activity 1 and from Activity 2  customView.context.startActivity(intent)

Comment: The `intent` instance in Activity 2 is _not_ the same as the instance in Activity 3. You need `startActivityForResult()` and then you need to use `setResult(int, Intent)`. Please read Onik's link.

Comment: @TheWanderer,thanks for your response and I never used this  option before so, I need to take a look into it how to implement this method.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) API to achieve your task.

**Activity2.kt**

```
class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val START_ACTIVITY_3_REQUEST_CODE = 0
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2)

        // Start Activity3
        val intent = Intent(this, Activity3::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, START_ACTIVITY_3_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == START_ACTIVITY_3_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val message = data!!.getStringExtra("message")
                Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity3.kt**

```
class Activity3 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity3)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        sendDataBackToPreviousActivity()
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    /**
     * Send data back to previous activity which start this one, you can call this method when users press on back key
     * or when users press on a view (button, image, etc) on this activity.
     */
    private fun sendDataBackToPreviousActivity() {
        val intent = Intent().apply {
            putExtra("message", "This is a message from Activity3")
            // Put your data here if you want.
        }
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you start Activity3 from Activity2.

Comment: @Thanks Son Trunong, I updated my code but still I miss something in the Activity 2.

Comment: What is `Main Class:`?

Comment: Can you please share the Kotlin code, it really hard to follow your coding that you posted above.

Comment: class TestMenuViewHolder(val customView: View,var Detail:TestDetail?=null):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customView)
{
    companion object {

        val TEST_TITLE_KEY="TEST_TITLE"
        val TEST_TITLE_NAME="TEST_NAME"
         }

init {
    customView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent= Intent(customView.context,TestMenuDetail::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(TEST_TITLE_KEY,Detail?.key)
        intent.putExtra(TEST_TITLE_NAME,Detail?.name)
        customView.context.startActivity(intent)
        println("Test Menu Clicks")
    }
}
}

Comment: Main Class is Activity 2

Comment: Why you call `val intent=Intent(this,TestProjectMenuDetail::class.java)` inside Activity2 instead of `val intent=Intent(this,Activity3::class.java)`?

Comment: It's the same  name. Activity3 =TestProjectMenuDetail

Comment: The error is related to parse response from the server. Please debug `fetchJSON` method in `RestaurantMenuDetail` to find root cause.

Comment: If I comment this part of code then I am not seeing the error. //startActivityForResult(intent, START_ACTIVITY_3_REQUEST_CODE)

Comment: That line of code only used to start another activity. It seems in that activity, you are fetching data from a server but the data format is not valid that why the app crashed.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.   startActivityForResult(intent, 0) contain only two variables where as fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) requires three variable.

Comment: In Activity3 when you call `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)`, then `onActivityResult` method will be called back on Activity2. `Activity.RESULT_OK` is `resultCode`, `intent` is `data`. No need to pass `requestCode` because the Android system will do it under the hood.

Comment: One more question. Is this format correct setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent) I didn't mention about TestMenuList class in TestMenuDetail

Comment: It's corect. Find more here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)

Comment: Sure, Thanks. I will take a look into it.

Comment: still no luck. Can we have a chat?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I would do:

Override the onBackPressed method and then pass the variable value inside the method with an Intent. And in activity 2 receive the value from activity 3.

In activity 3

```
@override
public void onBackPressed (){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);

    intent.put("value_key", value);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Receive value in activity 2

```
getIntent.getValue("value_key");
```

Don't forget to check the syntax, I just wrote it from my phone. Hope it helps!

Comment: I think this code is for Java and not for Kotlin. I am doing the same thing in my code.      val TestVar=Intent(this@TestMenuDetail,TestMenuList::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("TestVar2",navBarTitle2)
        println("Test Value $navBarTitle2")//Test Value Hello

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Imagine in current back stack you have Activity2 -> Activity3. When users press back key on Activity3 you start another instance of Activity2. Now in the back stack you have 2 instances of Activity2. The right way is using 'startActivityForResult()' API.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use SharedPreferences, and then clear them, after receiving data in previous activity. It's 100% effective way. Put it:

```
val sharedPreference =  getSharedPreferences("prefs name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
editor.putString("your value name","value")
editor.commit()
```

and get it:

```
sharedPreference.getString("your value name","default value")
```

but of course you have to open preferences again in previous activity ;)

```
val sharedPreference =  getSharedPreferences("prefs name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Comment: This is not a good way.

Comment: This is old one mate, now I would prefer to use `SavedStateHandle`.